# java.lang.NullPointerException in android Camera capturing

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is my code.Don't understand how to solve it.Saw many codes but failed. So posting it here.

```
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading picture");
        progressDialog.show();
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        //StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("CapturedPhotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

               // Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
               // Picasso.with(Storage_Capture_Picture.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);

                Toast.makeText(Storage_Capture_Picture.this,"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

LogCat

> 11-26 14:57:07.953 2912-2912/com.a.firebaseapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: com.a.firebaseapp, PID: 2912
>                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.a.firebaseapp/com.a.firebaseapp.Storage_Capture_Picture}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.a.firebaseapp/com.a.firebaseapp.Storage_Capture_Picture}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2786)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3736)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.a.firebaseapp/com.a.firebaseapp.Storage_Capture_Picture}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2773)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3736) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                        at com.a.firebaseapp.Storage_Capture_Picture.onActivityResult(Storage_Capture_Picture.java:64)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3359)

I am trying to make an app using fire-base storage that will capture image and store it to my fire-base storage.

When I run my app,it runs fine.I move to camera to capture image and I select okay button and it shows me unfortunately stopped.

I added all the permissions and gradle file to build.Shows me this two errors

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Comment: You should post your LogCat with these errors

Comment: `progressDialog==null`

Comment: When you want the full-size image, you must create a file to store it and pass the Uri of the file as an extra in the image capture intent.  See the [example code in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath).

Comment: @DimaKozhevin added LogCat.

Comment: showing problem in this line..StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

Comment: Well what is null in that line? Inspect all and report.

Comment: same line worked previously when i tried to get photos from gallery,but its not working now.

Comment: Ok. But answer my question. What is null in that code line?

Comment: `(Storage_Capture_Picture.java:64)`. What code on that line?

Comment: StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegmen‌​t());

Comment: Ok. Then now inspect what is null.

Comment: If you do not know 'how to inspect for null' then do not just sit down but ask.

Comment: how to inspect for null?

Answer (score 0):

If Your are doing this in an Activity You have to initialized Your ProgressDialog like

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);
```

And If You are doing this in a Fragment You have to initialized Your ProgressDialog like

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

You are not initializing the progressDialog correctly.

Comment: tried it but did not work.